# Python if/elseif construction as dictionary

Tags: python, list, if-statement

In Python I use regularly the following construct:

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
y = x[v] if v in x.keys() else None
```

where v is normally one of the dictionary values, and y gets the value of the dictionary if the key exists, otherwise None.

I was wondering if this is a desired construct or if it can be enhanced?

x[v] can be values as above, but I also use a similar construct to call a function depending on the value of v, like:

```
{'a': self.f1, 'b': self.f2, 'c': self.f3, 'd': self.f4}[v]()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described can be said like this:

"y should be the value of key "v" if "v" exists in the dictionary, else it should be "none"

In Python, that is:

```
y = x.get(v, None)
```

*Note:* `None` is already the default return value when the key is not present.

---

In your question, you also mention that sometimes your dictionaries contain references to methods. In this case, `y` would then be the method if it is not `None` and you can call it normally:

```
y(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or like in your example:

```
{'a': self.f1, 'b': self.f2, 'c': self.f3, 'd': self.f4}.get(v)()
```

*Note:* that if the key is not in the dictionary, then it will raise a `TypeError`

Comment: Should be noted that `None` is the default value for… er… default value.

Answer (score 6):

Normally you'd use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
y = x.get(v)
```

`.get()` takes a default parameter to return if `v` is not present in the dictionary, but if you omit it `None` is returned.

Even if you were to use an explicit key test, you don't need to use `.keys()`:

```
y = x[v] if v in x else None
```

Interestingly enough, the conditional expression option is slightly faster:

```
>>> [x.get(v) for v in 'acxz']  # demonstration of the test; two hits, two misses
[1, 3, None, None]
>>> timeit.timeit("for v in 'acxz': x.get(v)", 'from __main__ import x')
0.8269917964935303
>>> timeit.timeit("for v in 'acxz': x[v] if v in x else None", 'from __main__ import x')
0.67330002784729
```

until you avoid the attribute lookup for `.get()`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for v in 'acxz': get(v)", 'from __main__ import x; get = x.get')
0.6585619449615479
```

so if speed matters, store a reference to the `.get()` method (note the `get = x.get` assignment).

Comment: The timing is not complete, what if the key is NOT in the dict?

Comment: @InbarRose: `x` and `z` are not in the dict, `a` and `c` are.

Comment: Didn't catch that, nice. I am just shocked that it is faster than `get()` :)

Answer (score 1):

After spending many hours profiling some similar code, I found the most efficient way to do this is to use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)...

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(lambda: None, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
y = x[v]
```

...and the next most efficient is two key lookups...

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
y = x[v] if x in v else None
```

Both of these are much faster than this...

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
y = x.get(v, None)
```

...and this...

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
try:
    y = x[v]
except KeyError:
    y = None
```